# Bootstrap Video Carousel Play button/ left & right indicators not appearing

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, carousel

So I'm trying to have a carousel with 4 videos in it and am having some issues and can't see why. First of all I can only switch videos by using the circles at the bottom middle of the screen, I can't click on the left or right or the video to switch. When I do switch moving to the left works fine but when I go to the right the play button appears where the left indicator should be and when I play the video it pops back into the middle. Any help would be appreciated as I'm fairly stumped here. Here's my code.
Thanks in advance.

```
<div id="help--video-help-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#help--video-help-carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#help--video-help-carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#help--video-help-carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            <li data-target="#help--video-help-carousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <div class="item active">
                <video width="900" height="600" border="5" controls="controls">
                    <source src="help1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                </video>
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h3 class="h3-responsive">Help 1</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <video width="900" height="600" controls="controls">
                    <source src="help2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                </video>
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h3 class="h3-responsive">Help 2y</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <video width="900" height="600" controls="controls">
                    <source src="help3.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                </video>
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h3 class="h3-responsive">Help 3</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <video width="900" height="600" controls="controls">
                    <source src="help4.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                </video>
                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h3 class="h3-responsive">Help 4</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#help--video-help-carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#help--video-help-carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Johan was correct about `item` needing to be `carousel-item`. That fixed the code for me. Additionally, wrapping the carousel in a container seems to fix the controls. You may want to add a bottom margin to the controls, captions, and indicators as well.

```
<div class="container-fluid col-8 offset-2">
<div id="help--video-help-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators" style="margin-bottom: 60px;">
        <li data-target="#help--video-help-carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#help--video-help-carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#help--video-help-carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        <li data-target="#help--video-help-carousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
            <video width="900" height="600" border="5" controls="controls">
                <source src="help1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block" style="margin-bottom: 60px;">
                <h3 class="h3-responsive">Help 1</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <video width="900" height="600" controls="controls">
                <source src="help2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block" style="margin-bottom: 60px;">
                <h3 class="h3-responsive">Help 2y</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <video width="900" height="600" controls="controls">
                <source src="help3.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block" style="margin-bottom: 60px;">
                <h3 class="h3-responsive">Help 3</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <video width="900" height="600" controls="controls">
                <source src="help4.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block" style="margin-bottom: 60px;">
                <h3 class="h3-responsive">Help 4</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#help--video-help-carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev" style="margin-bottom: 60px;">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#help--video-help-carousel" role="button" data-slide="next" style="margin-bottom: 60px;">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Screenshot of carousel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7C2E.png)

Comment: Having carousel-item instead of item breaks it for me and I don't know why. I know it should be carousel-item form reading the documentation but it does break it. I also copy and pasted your code with and without carousel item and there's no option to go onto the next or previous video. Must be something local going on. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you're using Bootstrap 4? According to this site: https://www.quackit.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_4/differences_between_bootstrap_3_and_bootstrap_4.cfm, carousels used the `item` class in bs3, but changed to the `carousel-item` in bs4.

Answer (score 0):

In Bootstrap v4.x (latest) the individual carousel elements class is not 'item' it's 'carousel-item'.

Also you've set a class 'd-none d-md-block' on just one of the elements which is inconsistent at best.
You might want to look into Bootstraps use of alignment in the carousel https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/carousel/#slides-only where they use 'd-block' (class="d-block w-100") on all elements in the example.

Haven't tested but that might be it.

Comment: Ah didn't notice the "d-none d-md-block" nit that must of been a copy and paste error good spot. But it still didn't make a difference fixing it. 
I also looked into 'carousel-item' instead of just 'item' but that seems to break the carousel for some reason. All the items just appear individually one under the other and then at the bottom there's what looks like a carousel but you can't go next or previous. Any other ideas? Thanks for the help anyway by the way I've been so stuck here.