# Boostrap 4 Carousel video controls disappear on right slide

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, html5-video, carousel

I am using a combination of Images and Videos in Bootstrap Carousel 4. HTML5 Video controls work fine if I slide the carousel in left direction but if slide carousel in the right direction, video controls either disappear or move towards the extreme left.

I found a reference here [Bootstrap Video Carousel Play button/ left & right indicators not appearing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51152277/bootstrap-video-carousel-play-button-left-right-indicators-not-appearing), but none of the provided answers work.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div id="homeCarousel" class="col-lg-12 col-md-12  no-padding">
  <div id="demo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="7000">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div id="p_lt_ctl00_pageplaceholder_p_lt_ctl00_UniversalPageViewer_viewElem">

      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920x675" alt="" width="1920" height="675" style="display:block;">
        <div class="carousel-caption carousel-caption-2" style="display:block;">
          <h3 class="carousel-title">Test</h3>
          <p class="carousel-detail">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920x675" alt="" width="1920" height="675" style="display:block;">

        <div class="carousel-caption carousel-caption-1" style="display:block;">
          <h3 class="carousel-title">Test</h3>
          <p class="carousel-detail">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor.</p>

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920x675" alt="" width="1920" height="675" style="display:block;">

        <div class="carousel-caption carousel-caption-3" style="display:none;">
          <h3 class="carousel-title">Test</h3>
          <p class="carousel-detail">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <video controls="controls" width="1920" height="675" style="display:block;">
        <source src="https://www.quirksmode.org/html5/videos/big_buck_bunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">    
      </video>

      </div>

    </div>
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="1" class=""></li>
      <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="2" class=""></li>
      <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="3" class=""></li>
    </ol>
    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#demo" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#demo" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: where's your code?

Comment: @SergChernata Updated the code as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should avoid setting height and width in `html`. Setting those measurements from within `css` will give you much more predictable and flexible results.

```css
.carousel-item img,
.carousel-item video {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div id="homeCarousel" class="col-lg-12 col-md-12  no-padding">
  <div id="demo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="7000">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div id="p_lt_ctl00_pageplaceholder_p_lt_ctl00_UniversalPageViewer_viewElem">

      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920x675" alt="" style="display:block;">
        <div class="carousel-caption carousel-caption-2" style="display:block;">
          <h3 class="carousel-title">Test</h3>
          <p class="carousel-detail">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920x675" alt="" style="display:block;">

        <div class="carousel-caption carousel-caption-1" style="display:block;">
          <h3 class="carousel-title">Test</h3>
          <p class="carousel-detail">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor.</p>

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920x675" alt="" style="display:block;">

        <div class="carousel-caption carousel-caption-3" style="display:none;">
          <h3 class="carousel-title">Test</h3>
          <p class="carousel-detail">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <video controls="controls" style="display:block;">
        <source src="https://www.quirksmode.org/html5/videos/big_buck_bunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">    
      </video>

      </div>

    </div>
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="1" class=""></li>
      <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="2" class=""></li>
      <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="3" class=""></li>
    </ol>
    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#demo" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#demo" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: chermata I tried the solution provided by you but it doesn't help.